# I need to join html elements with js

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby, svg

[image: The boxes with blue border are the div with class val]I am working with ruby on rails code,
I have a .erc file where it returns a fragment of html code, it performs a foreach to an array, this fragment
of code is executed 12 times since there are three graphs and each of the graphs contains 4 points which are those of the dot class
What I need to do is be able to join the 4 points by graph using an SVG line, which I have not been able to do.[image: result]

CSS:

```
.val {
          width: 100%;
          position: relative;
          transform: translateX(70%);
          z-index: 1;
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
          border: solid 1px blue;


          .result-bar {
            border: solid 1px red;

            .dot {
              position: absolute;
              width: 10px;
              height: 10px;
              border-radius: 100%;
              background: $soft-blue;
              transform: translateX(10px);
            }

          }

          p {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          }
        }ere
```

CODE RUBY AND JS :

```
type <% ary.each do |x| %>
  <div class="val" style="height: calc(100% / <%= range.to_a.length %>);">
    <% if x == val %>
      <div class="result-bar">
        <div class="dot"> 
        </div>
        <svg id="_svg"></svg>
      </div>      
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
<div class="letter-bar-range">
  <%= content_tag(:p, "#{letter}") %>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var puntos = document.querySelectorAll(".dot");
  var svgElement = document.getElementById("_svg");
  var chart = document.querySelector('.result-bar');
  var poschart = chart.getBoundingClientRect();
  var line = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'line');
 
  if(puntos.length >= 2) {

    var punto1 = puntos[0];
    var pos1 = punto1.getBoundingClientRect();
    var punto2 = puntos[1];
    var pos2 = punto2.getBoundingClientRect();
    
    if(pos1 && pos2) {

    var x1 = pos1.x + pos1.width / 2 - poschart.x;
    var y1 = pos1.y + pos1.height / 2 - poschart.y;
    var x2 = pos2.x + pos2.width / 2 - poschart.x;
    var y2 = pos2.y + pos2.height / 2 - poschart.y;
  
    line.setAttribute('x1', x1);
    line.setAttribute('y1', y1);
    line.setAttribute('x2', x2);
    line.setAttribute('y2', y2);
    line.setAttribute('stroke', 'red');
    line.setAttribute('stroke-width', '1');
    svgElement.appendChild(line);    
    }    
  }

</script>here
```

I have already done too many implementations but I cannot meet the requirement.I've had this problem for 3 days

Comment: Please edit your question to include code that can reproduce the result you are seeing. As of now it is missing some key elements. Most notably the positioning of your relative `.val` elements. I believe I know how to fix your problem but I can't be certain without the ability to reproduce it myself

Comment: Did you search before you asked the question? [https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsvg%5D+draw+SVG+line+between+DIVs](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsvg%5D+draw+SVG+line+between+DIVs)

Comment: I have searched on different sites, the ones that have helped me get the current result have been these links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70387534/connecting-divs-with-svg-line      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19382872/how-to-connect-html-divs-with-lines